# about page library not working app crash when clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an about page in a web view app but whenever i click on about app crashes

I have used android's navigation drawer template and using android about page library by medyo everything else is fine dependencies, repositories just stuck with java

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        View aboutPage = new AboutPage(this)
                .isRTL(false)
                .setImage(R.drawable.icons_us)
                .addGroup("Connect with us")
                .addEmail("elmehdi.sakout@gmail.com")
                .addWebsite("http://medyo.github.io/")
                .addFacebook("the.medy")
                .addTwitter("medyo80")
                .addYoutube("UCdPQtdWIsg7_pi4mrRu46vA")
                .addPlayStore("com.ideashower.readitlater.pro")
                .addGitHub("medyo")
                .addInstagram("medyo80")
                .create();
        setContentView(aboutPage);
```

Comment: can you add your logcat, please. What's the error with the crash?

Comment: put your drawer activity code...Its is not an error of Aboutpage

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.appsquad.gcufmobile, PID: 15582

Comment: can you put your whole activity code ??

Comment: I told about java class file which contain drawer ?(Whole code)